# plt.plot(x,y) - AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, error-handling, numpy-ndarray

I have such a dataframe:

[image: pandas]

The types of the data are:

```
index                                                int64
Time                  datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(60)]
RAM Total                                            int64
RAM Used                                             int64
```

I would like to plot the trendline for RAM Used using this code:

```
x = df['Time']
y = df['RAM Used']

plt.plot(x, y)

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

plt.show()
```

But I got ths AssertionError and an empty plot:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-9180041638db> in <module>()
----> 1 plt.plot(x, y)
      2 
      3 z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
      4 p = np.poly1d(z)
      5 plt.plot(x,p(x),"r--")

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in __init__(self, block, axis, do_integrity_check, fastpath)
   1538     ):
   1539         assert isinstance(block, Block), type(block)
-> 1540         assert isinstance(axis, Index), type(axis)
   1541 
   1542         if fastpath is not lib.no_default:

AssertionError: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How do I have to amend my code?

**EDIT**: It seems to be due to an issue with the `Time`-column. When instead using `index` as x-axis I do not get an error.